# Loop through all ListBoxes for selected items and transfer over to one ListBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Here is what I have so far it looks like it will gather the correct amount of selected items from each listbox but instead of outputting the selected ones it outputs the first one over and over.

```
TabPage page = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
            var controls = page.Controls;
            foreach (var control in controls)
            {
                if (control is ListBox)
                {
                    ListBox listbox = control as ListBox;
                    foreach (var item2 in listbox.SelectedItems)
                    {
                        FilterColLB.Items.Add(ShipmentBox.SelectedItem);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reference `ShipmentBox.SelectedItem` inside the loop:

```
foreach (var item2 in listbox.SelectedItems)
{
    FilterColLB.Items.Add(item2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something more like:

```
        foreach(ListBox lb in tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<ListBox>())
        {
            foreach(var item in lb.SelectedItems)
            {
                FilterColLB.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }
```